# PHP order/sort an array based on order of another array

Tags: php, arrays

This should be fairly simple but my brain can't seem to process this at the moment. Hoping you can help :)

I have an array of posts that each have a tag, looks something like this:

```
Array(
   [0] = Array('Computers', postObject),
   [1] = Array('Sports', postObject),
   [2] = Array('Computers', postObject),
   [3] = Array('Business', postObject)
)
```

I was using `asort()` which seemed to sort the posts alphabetically, but I now need to sort the posts based on a specified order (stored in an array) that might have extra values.

```
Array(
   [0] = 'Sports',
   [1] = 'Fashion',
   [2] = 'Business',
   [3] = 'Computers',
   [4] = 'Stocks'
 )
```

I'm expecting the first array to be sorted like this:

```
Array(
   [0] = Array('Sports', postObject),
   [1] = Array('Business', postObject),
   [2] = Array('Computers', postObject),
   [3] = Array('Computers', postObject)
)
```

I don't think there is a simple php function to call, can you please advise ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`usort`](http://php.net/usort) function, which sorts the array using a user-defined comparison function.

An untested solution can be:

```
$categories = array_flip($categories); // not needed by original solution
usort($posts, function($a, $b) use ($categories) {
    // original solution:
    // return array_search($a[0], $categories) > array_search($b[0], $categories);

    // shameless CAP (copy-and-paste) from Mike Brant's answer
    // actually, performs better, and I hope that he doesn't mind :)
    return $categories[$a[0]] > $categories[$b[0]];

});
```

This solution is applicable for PHP v >= 5.3, since it uses [anonymous functions and closures](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

If you are using PHP < 5.3, you can use [`ksort`](http://php.net/ksort) function, like this (again, untested):

```
$new_arr = array();
$categories = array_flip($categories);
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    $new_arr[$categories[$post[0]]] = $post;
}
ksort($new_arr);
```

Comment: "Provide context for links

Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."

Comment: @Stoic, the usort solution seems to be pretty close, for some reason it's still not following the correct order though

Comment: Hmm, both of these solutions, your new one and mikes don't seem to order correctly :|

Comment: are you sure? I just tested my original as well as the current code, and it seems to work correctly. `usort` updates the `$posts` variable itself (it uses by-reference passing of parameters) and therefore, your updated (sorted) array is available in `$posts` itself, after the above method. I am sure that you are aware about, but I can not think of any other reason.

Comment: My bad, it was because of a case sensitive issue - nice work man! I had to add a bit of code to get it working, but you did solve what I asked :)

Comment: For the record:
`return array_search(strtolower($a[0]), array_map('strtolower', $orderArray)) > array_search(strtolower($b[0]), array_map('strtolower', $orderArray));`

Answer (score 0):

I would consider `usort()`. Example:

```
$array = array(...); // your multi-dimension array to sort
$sort_order_array = array(...); // your array defining sort order
$sort_order_array_flipped = array_flip($sort_order_array);

usort($array, function($a, $b) use ($sort_order_array_flipped) {
    return $sort_order_array_flipped[$a[0]] > $sort_order_array_flipped[$b[0]];
});
```

Note that I flipped the sort order array in able to make it easy to lookup the order value (0, 1, 2) based on the value stored in the main array. This is actually computationaly faster than doing a key loop with every iteration of `usort()`